# JS alert on Magento Custom Option click

Tags: javascript, magento, prototypejs

I have a radio button custom option with 3 options. On selection of option 2, for example, I wish a simple JS `alert()` to popup with a message regarding this selection, not on all of them, only one.

The problem I'm finding is that to make it compatible with all products they have JS generated ID's and class names so there's little in the way of a pattern to follow to ensure my code works on all products.

I could do it via just looking for that element and getting the second one with `getElementByTag()`, however I want a Magento-friendly way to do it as I'm heading towards my certification over the coming months and want to ensure my practices are kept in-line with Magento rather than "working around" it.

Example code (ID's, classes and names generated on the fly by Magento)

```
<dd class="last">
    <ul id="options-54765-list" class="options-list">
        <li>
            <input type="radio" class="radio  validate-one-required-by-name product-custom-option" onclick="opConfig.reloadPrice()" name="options[54765]" id="options_54765_2" value="210674" />
            <span class="label"><label for="options_54765_2">Colour Edge </label></span>
            <script type="text/javascript">$('options_54765_2').advaiceContainer = 'options-54765-container';$('options_54765_2').callbackFunction = 'validateOptionsCallback';</script>
        </li>
        <li>
            <input type="radio" class="radio  validate-one-required-by-name product-custom-option" onclick="opConfig.reloadPrice()" name="options[54765]" id="options_54765_3" value="210673" />
            <span class="label"><label for="options_54765_3">Gallery Wrap </label></span>
            <script type="text/javascript">$('options_54765_3').advaiceContainer = 'options-54765-container';$('options_54765_3').callbackFunction = 'validateOptionsCallback';</script>
        </li>
        <li>
            <input type="radio" class="radio  validate-one-required-by-name product-custom-option" onclick="opConfig.reloadPrice()" name="options[54765]" id="options_54765_4" value="210672" />
            <span class="label"><label for="options_54765_4">White Edge </label></span>
            <script type="text/javascript">$('options_54765_4').advaiceContainer = 'options-54765-container';$('options_54765_4').callbackFunction = 'validateOptionsCallback';</script>
        </li>
    </ul>
</dd>
```

Comment: can you post a bit of the html for the radio buttons?

Comment: hi, can i get the complete details of this option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To accomplish this, on that product, in the design tab, add in a custom block, like so:

```
<reference name="before_body_end">
    <block type="your_module/product" name="option.select.js" template="path/to/template.phtml" />
</reference>
```

In your new block, grab the `Mage::registry('current_product');`, and call `getProductOptions()`. Filter it down based on whatever criteria. Now, the best might be, depending on if this needs to be reused much, to add a column to `Catalog_Model_Product_Option_Value` table in the database, and extend the admin templates so you are checking a box, or using a drop-down, or typing some text to get the confirmation to pop up.

Then, in the `protected function _toHtml() {}` function, output your JS for the confirmation box.

That is how I would do it.